# TypedQuery with ManyToMany relations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a problem to create query with TypedQuery interface, NamedQuery and many-to-many relationship.
Here is my Report entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REPORT")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Report.NAMED_QUERY.FIND_USERS, query = "SELECT r.users FROM Report r WHERE r = :report")})

public class Report {

  public interface NAMED_QUERY {
      String FIND_USERS = "Report.findUsers";
  }

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "REPORT_USER", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "REPORT_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"))
  private Set<User> users;

  //another fields, getters and setters
}
```

And User Entity. Here i have no field that maps many-to-many relation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

  //fields, getters and setters

}
```

I have no idea how to use this named query.

```
public List<User> findUsersRelatedToReport(Report report) {
    TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Report.NAMED_QUERY.FIND_USERS, User.class)
            .setParameter("report", report);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

In the end I have exception:

```
Type specified for TypedQuery [package_name.User] is incompatible with query return type [interface java.util.Set]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use collection valued attributes (in JPA specification terminology: collection_valued_path_expression) in SELECT.

That's why query is bit more complex, one way is following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(u)
FROM User u 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT r 
    FROM Report r 
    WHERE r = :report AND u MEMBER OF r.users)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing data type of Users in your report class to List.

`private List<User> users;`

instead of

```
private Set<User> users;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return set of users as a column in your select that is causing the error.

I think you could try to select data from User table. Try something like that:
`SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.report = :report`

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I've also hit this recently and came up with more elegant solution: it's true you cannot use collection_valued_path in select expression, but you definitely can do joins over this path:

```
SELECT u FROM Report r JOIN r.users u where r = :report
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
SELECT r.users FROM Report r WHERE r = :report
```

write this

```
SELECT u FROM Report r join r.users u WHERE r = :report
```